# Twisted Authentication with Perspective Broker

Tags: python, twisted

Has been studying Tvisted week, read the book and most of the docks, but I can not understand a single moment. From Twisted docs
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/core/howto/pb-cred.html
server

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Copyright (c) 2009 Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.

from zope.interface import implements

from twisted.spread import pb
from twisted.cred import checkers, portal
from twisted.internet import reactor

class MyPerspective(pb.Avatar):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def perspective_foo(self, arg):
        print "I am", self.name, "perspective_foo(",arg,") called on", self

class MyRealm:
    implements(portal.IRealm)
    def requestAvatar(self, avatarId, mind, *interfaces):
        if pb.IPerspective not in interfaces:
            raise NotImplementedError
        return pb.IPerspective, MyPerspective(avatarId), lambda:None

p = portal.Portal(MyRealm())
c = checkers.InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse(user1="pass1",
                                                     user2="pass2")
p.registerChecker(c)
reactor.listenTCP(8800, pb.PBServerFactory(p))
reactor.run()
```

client

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Copyright (c) 2009 Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.

from twisted.spread import pb
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.cred import credentials

def main():
    factory = pb.PBClientFactory()
    reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8800, factory)
    def1 = factory.login(credentials.UsernamePassword("user1", "pass1"))
    def1.addCallback(connected)
    reactor.run()

def connected(perspective):
    print "got perspective1 ref:", perspective
    print "asking it to foo(13)"
    perspective.callRemote("foo", 13)

main()
```

if the user enters the wrong password:

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: twisted.cred.error.UnauthorizedLogin:
```

I instead of an exception, tell the user that he does not put the correct password?\bad username

I tried to change:

```
c = checkers.InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse(user1="pass1",user2="pass2") 
p.registerChecker(c)
```

on

```
passwords = {
    'admin': 'aaa',
    'user1': 'bbb',
    'user2': 'ccc'
    }
p.registerChecker(PasswordDictChecker(passwords))
class PasswordDictChecker(object):
    implements(checkers.ICredentialsChecker)
    credentialInterfaces = (credentials.IUsernamePassword,)

    def __init__(self, passwords):
        "passwords: a dict-like object mapping usernames to passwords"
        self.passwords = passwords

    def requestAvatarId(self, credentials):
        username = credentials.username
        if self.passwords.has_key(username):
            if credentials.password == self.passwords[username]:
                return defer.succeed(username)
            else:
                return defer.fail(
                    credError.UnauthorizedLogin("Bad password"))
        else:
            return defer.fail(
                credError.UnauthorizedLogin("No such user"))
```

but got an error and I think this is the wrong way.

P.S. I know how to do authentication without Perspective Broker...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement retry, do it entirely in the client.  You should **not** change the server to report messages like "Bad password" or "No such user", as these leak information to an attacker.

To have the client retry, add an errback to the login Deferred that prompts for a new password (and maybe a new user) and calls login again.

Comment: Oh yeah it's pretty simple solution.